# NGRX Effect infinite loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm struggling with the implementation of Ngrx Effect (straight from the documenation).
I'm always ending with an infinite loop :

```js
  updateSomething$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(somActions.fetchUpdateSomething),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.someService.fetchUpdateSomething().pipe(
          map(({ someData }) =>
            someOtherActions.theAction({
              payload: someData,
            })
          ),
          catchError(() => EMPTY)
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

The action I dispatch to trigger this comes from a component :

```js
this.store.dispatch(somActions.fetchUpdateSomething());
```

The targeted action (somActions.fetchUpdateSomething) looks like this :

```js
export const fetchUpdateSomething = createAction(
  SomeActionTypes.FETCH_UPDATE_SOMETHING
);
```

And the desired action to be triggered by the Effect :

```js
export const theAction = createAction(
  SomeOtherActionTypes.UPDATE_SOMETHING,
  props<{ payload: someData }>()
);
```

I struggled hours yesterday on this. The action `theAction is stuck in an infinite loop.
The reducer :

```js
export const myReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(
    someOtherActions.theAction,
    (state, { payload }) => ({
      ...state,
      ...payload,
    })
  )
);
```

Any help will be welcomed, thank you.

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the issue : It was in the service which, when retrieving the value in the store before performing the API call, caused the infinite loop.